# How to access the data attributes of that element in case it is used with document.addEventListener

Tags: jquery

Earlier i was using jquery  dynamically generated  checkbox check and unchek  events and everything was working fine under Browser .

But i realized these events are not getting captured on mobile , so the reado i am using document.addEventListener to capture them

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.ui-checkbox-on')) {
           var cost = $(this).data('cost');
          alert(cost);
    }
    else if ($(event.target).is('.ui-checkbox-off')) {
              var cost = $(this).data('cost');
        alert(cost);
     }    
     }, true 
);
```

But my question when i am tring to access the data attributes of that elemnt they are getting as undefined .

Please see this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/38/

and please let me know how to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are biding the handler to the document object inside the handler `this` is referring to the document object which does not have the `data-cost` that is why you are getting `undefined`.

Since you are targeting `ui-checkbox-on/off` element, which is referred by `e.target` use that to fetch the data

```
var cost = $(event.target).data('cost');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zm01q8ah/)